# どのように１ページごとに表示させるアイテム数とページネータをコントロールすればいいか

Tags: python, html, flask

どのように１ページごとに表示させるアイテム数とページネータをコントロールすればいいでしょうか？

５つの要素を１つのhtml上に表示させたいです。
例えば、２１この要素があった時、５つのページを作ってそれぞれに５つずつ配置したいです。

app.pyに

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter

@app.route("/page", methods=["GET","POST"])
def page():

    users = {
        "data":[
            {
                “Name”:”Tom”,
                “Age”:”21”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”John”,
                “Age”:”40”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Juddy”,
                “Age”:”37”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Kei”,
                “Age”:”46”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Wu”,
                “Age”:”12”
            },
            {“Name”:”Rey”,
                “Age”:”47”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Boo”,
                “Age”:”25”
            },
            {
                “Name”:”Cho”,
                “Age”:”48”
            }
        ],
        “Date”:”20180403”
    }

   users = users["data"]


    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=5)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(users), search=search)


    return render_template(“index.html", json=users,pagination=pagination)
```

と書いて、index.htmlに

```
<div>
    {% for i in range(json|length) %}
    <div>
            <h3>{{ json[i]['Name'] }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ json[i]['Age'] }}</h3>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}
```

と書きました。
しかし、今の状態だと、８つの要素全てが１つのhtmlに表示されてしまいます。
５つの要素を１つのページに、３つの要素を別のページに表示される仕組み・ページネータを作るには何が問題でしょうか？またどう修正すればいいでしょうか？

*以前、https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920528/how-can-i-control-the-number-of-items-are-shown-in-one-html　にも投稿しました。
回答が求めているものではなかったのでこちらにも投稿させていただきます。

Comment: 使用しているPaginationとは、どのクラスですか？ 質問にimport文も含めてください。また、そのPaginationの使い方を説明している公式のドキュメントのURLも教えてください

Answer (score 2, accepted):

表示するデータの個数が多い場合には、複数のページに分割する「ページネーション」を使用しますが、flaskの場合には`flask-paginate`という拡張機能を使うと「ページネーション」の機能を容易に追加できます。

`flask-paginate`では、クエリーパラメータに`page`を使うのがデフォルトで、最初のページのURLは`http://example.com/page`又は`http://example.com/page?page=1`、次のページのURLは`http://example.com/page?page=2`というようになります。

`request.args.get`の`default`オプションはクエリーパラメータがない場合のデフォルトの値になるので`1`にします。そうしておいて、`users`のデータから、最初のページであれば[0:5]、次のページであれば[5:10]でスライスすれば、最初のページには５つの要素が、次のページには3つの要素が表示されるようにできます。

```
page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
page_users = users[(page - 1)*5: page*5]
```

テンプレートには、`json=users`とすべてのデータを渡すのではなく、`json=page_users`として該当のページのデータだけを渡すようにします。

```
return render_template(“index.html", json=page_users,　pagination=pagination)
```

また、`pagenation`の設定の箇所では、searchという変数が定義されていないので`False`に修正し、ページ当たりの表示数を`per_page`オプションで設定します。

```
pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(users), search=False, per_page=5)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。`users[p*5: p*5 + 5]`　のp変数はどこで定義されていますか？

Comment: 入力ミスなので、修正しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。page/page?page=0 でアクセスすると、htmlに５つ要素は表示されますが、`{{ pagination.links }}`　が表示されません・・・。何が原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみに、found 0 records, displaying -9 - 0　と{{ pagination.info }}　ではなぜかマイナスの値が出てしまいます・・・

Comment: `index.html`の左の文字列記号が"ではなくスマートなものになってしまっています.些末ですが6文字制限に引っかかって編集できないのでコメントでバグ報告しておきます.

Comment: と思いましたがこれ元の質問のサンプルコードからこうですね

Comment: Flaskのサンプルコード [flask-paginate 0.5.0 documentation — flask-paginate 0.5.0 documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/) 見るとdefaultが1ですし,0始まりではなく1始まりである必要性があるのでは.その場合userのスライスではpage - 1する必要がありそうです.

Comment: flask-paginateのdefaultは、1のようですね。回答を修正しておきます。それとpagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(users), search=search) をチェックしてみます。

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji  ありがとうございます。修正点を反映させたのですが、８つ全部が一つのページに反映され、また　`{{ pagination.links }}`　が表示されませんでした。どう修正すればいいですか？

Comment: 最後の修正で{{ pagination.links }}が表示されるようになっていました。